# Google Foobar: Java code compiles without a prob1em on my machine, but google foobar gives error "

Tags: java, compilation

Google foobar gives : "Error compiling the code, please try again later."

Here is my code:

```
package com.google.challenges; 

public class Answer {
public static String[] answer(String[] l) { 
    for (int seg = 3; seg >= 1; seg--) {
        bubbleSort(l, seg);
    }
    return l;
}

public static int getSubVersion(String a, int segment) {
    int firstSegEnd = a.indexOf('.');
    int secondSegEnd = a.indexOf('.', firstSegEnd + 1);
    if (segment == 1) {
        if (firstSegEnd != -1)
            return Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0, firstSegEnd));
        else
            return Integer.parseInt(a);
    } else if (segment == 2) {
        if (firstSegEnd != -1 && secondSegEnd != -1)
            return Integer.parseInt(a.substring(firstSegEnd + 1, secondSegEnd));
        else if (firstSegEnd != -1)
            return Integer.parseInt(a.substring(firstSegEnd + 1));
    } else if (segment == 3) {
        if (secondSegEnd != -1)
            return Integer.parseInt(a.substring(secondSegEnd + 1));
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void bubbleSort(String[] l, int seg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < l.length-1; j++)
            if (getSubVersion(l[j], seg) > getSubVersion(l[j+1], seg)) {
                String temp = l[j];
                l[j] = l[j+1];
                l[j+1] = temp;
            }
}
}
```

This code works completely fine on my computer - the only difference is that I removed the "package com.google.challenges;" line from the copy on my computer so that it would compile. I compiled with Java 7 and 8, both compiled successfully. **Furthermore**, Google Foobar USUALLY provides a compilation error when code doesn't compile!

Anyone else have this problem? I am sure it is a problem with Google!
What do I do? Please help, the challenge has less than 72 more hours for me to finish, and my solution *does* work.

Thanks!!

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?

Comment: The fact that it says "please try again later" implies that it is not a problem with this code, as if the code were faulty, it would be faulty later too.

Comment: @SamOrozco, I am not getting any information about the compilation error. The error message I see is ""Error compiling the code, please try again later."

Comment: @Andy I agree, but how do I get it to work? I will be locked from the challenge, and the challenge is important to me.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. It's really doesn't matter what kind of code you will try to submit. Ever with the basic thing is still display "Error compiling the code, please try again later." I have tried probably 10 different version of solution I had and all works great locally, but Google still show compilation error. Looks like someone who sits near computer and verifying submissions just tired, shutdown computer and left for vacation to Hawaii :))

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipO-Q57u1y9lDlAYmbGqANN5Elr8X91q-RK81_G8HfdvuVl75LJwgLps4r1VeRomqg?key=T1A0OFlTaHpzSm5NNDF4Sk80aG0yNUoxZGhJWVJB

```
package com.google.challenges;

public class Answer {
    public static int[] answer(int[] data, int n) {

        int i = 0;

        while (i < data.length) {

            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if (data[j] == data[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            int newLength = data.length - count;
            if (count <= n) {
                newLength++;
            }
            int[] newValues = new int[newLength];
            int track = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if (data[j] != data[i]) {
                    newValues[track] = data[j];
                    track++;
                }

                if (j == i && count <= n) {
                    newValues[track] = data[j];
                    track++;
                }
            }

            if (count <= n) {
                i++;
            }

            data = newValues;
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```